# Thickness of objects with transparent, translucent, etc. shaders

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders

Do objects with these shaders need volume in order to work?  In other words, can I use an object with no thickness; e.g., 4 points on a plane?

I want to put a translucent object in front of an emission object to make it look more realistic as glowing object and was wondering if the translucent object needs thickness.

I'm guessing that it doesn't need thickness, and that if I gave it some thickness then I could use the volume shader to tweak its appearance.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Transparent and translucent surface shaders can have no thickness.

Here's a simple plane with no thickness and a translucent shader in front of the only lightsource as an example:

[image]

I'm assuming you're solely talking about cycles.